# Count number of consecutive rows that are greater than current row value but less than the value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Say I have the following sample dataframe (there are about 25k rows in the real dataframe)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,3,2,9,1,0,4,7,3,2], 'B': [9,8,3,5,5,5,5,8,0,4]})
df
   A  B
0  0  9
1  3  8
2  2  3
3  9  5
4  1  5
5  0  5
6  4  5
7  7  8
8  3  0
9  2  4
```

For the column A I need to know how many next and previous rows are greater than current row value but less than value in column B.

So my expected output is :

```
A   B next count  previous count
0   9     2          0
3   8     0          0
2   3     0          1
9   5     0          0
1   5     0          0
0   5     2          1
4   5     1          0
7   8     0          0
3   0     0          2
2   4     0          0
```

**Explanation :**

- First row is calculated as : since 3 and 2 are greater than 0  but less than corresponding B value 8 and 3
- Second row is calculated as : since next value 2 is not greater than 3
- Third row is calculated as : since 9 is greater than 2 but not greater than its corresponding B value

Similarly, `previous count` is calculated

**Note :** I know how to solve this problem by looping using list comprehension or using the pandas apply method but still I won't mind a clear and concise `apply` approach. I was looking for a more `pandaic` approach.

##### My Solution

Here is the apply solution, which I think is inefficient. Also, as people said that there might be no `vector` solution for the question.  So as mentioned, a more efficient apply solution will be accepted for this question.

This is what I have tried.

This function gets the number of previous/next rows that satisfy the condition.

```
def get_prev_next_count(row):
    next_nrow = df.loc[row['index']+1:,['A', 'B']]
    prev_nrow = df.loc[:row['index']-1,['A', 'B']][::-1]
    if (next_nrow.size == 0):
        return 0, ((prev_nrow.A > row.A) & (prev_nrow.A < prev_nrow.B)).argmin()
    if (prev_nrow.size == 0):
        return ((next_nrow.A > row.A) & (next_nrow.A < next_nrow.B)).argmin(), 0
    return (((next_nrow.A > row.A) & (next_nrow.A < next_nrow.B)).argmin(), ((prev_nrow.A > row.A) & (prev_nrow.A < prev_nrow.B)).argmin())
```

##### Generating output :

```
df[['next count', 'previous count']] = df.reset_index().apply(get_prev_next_count, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

##### Output :

This gives us the expected output

```
df
   A  B  next count  previous count
0  0  9           2               0
1  3  8           0               0
2  2  3           0               1
3  9  5           0               0
4  1  5           0               0
5  0  5           2               1
6  4  5           1               0
7  7  8           0               0
8  3  0           0               2
9  2  4           0               0
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a vectorial way to achieve this

Comment: okay how about at least the first part, don't compare with B but a constant value say x

Comment: @mozway okay don't compare just how many next values are between current row value and row_value+x(some value) say : any vectorial way

Comment: why is used argmin and not sum for count matched conditions (count Trues)?

Comment: @jezrael because we need the count of just the first consecutive trues

Comment: so need index of first matched value, not count.

Comment: `.argmin` basically gives me count of number of true values, by giving the row number of first `false` value

Comment: say I have `np.array( [True, True, True,True, True, False, False, True, False]).argmin()` which gives me `5` the index of first min value which will obviously be the count of consecutive true values, this is what is expected

Comment: @jezrael I see the problem now, I won't get the count if there are all true values in the frame, eg `np.array( [True, True, True,True, True]).argmin()` gives me 0(obviously) where as 5 was expected according to my code

Comment: I see it, interesting. I think need count all Trues - need sum. For only first consecutive Trues need argmin

Comment: is there other efficient way to get the count of first consecutive trues? or I ll have to induce a false value to the frame!

Comment: I think need numba solution for this for increase performance, not loops by apply.

Comment: I think you can ask some numba expert for solution, I found something which can be helpfull - https://louisabraham.github.io/articles/broadcasting-and-numba.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some optimizations:

1. You don't need to `reset_index()` you can access the index with `.name`
2. If you only pass `df[['A']]` instead of the whole frame, that may help.
3. `prev_nrow.empty` is the same as `(prev_nrow.size == 0)`
4. Applied different logic to get the desired value via `first_false`, this speeds things up significantly.

```
def first_false(val1, val2, A):
    i = 0
    for x, y in zip(val1, val2):
        if A < x < y:
            i += 1
        else:
            break
    return i

def get_prev_next_count(row):
    A = row['A']
    next_nrow = df.loc[row.name+1:,['A', 'B']]
    prev_nrow = df2.loc[row.name-1:,['A', 'B']]
    if next_nrow.empty:
        return 0, first_false(prev_nrow.A, prev_nrow.B, A)
    if prev_nrow.empty:
        return first_false(next_nrow.A, next_nrow.B, A), 0
    return (first_false(next_nrow.A, next_nrow.B, A),
            first_false(prev_nrow.A, prev_nrow.B, A))

df2 = df[::-1].copy() # Shave a tiny bit of time by only reversing it once~

df[['next count', 'previous count']] = df[['A']].apply(get_prev_next_count, axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  next count  previous count
0  0  9           2               0
1  3  8           0               0
2  2  3           0               1
3  9  5           0               0
4  1  5           0               0
5  0  5           2               1
6  4  5           1               0
7  7  8           0               0
8  3  0           0               2
9  2  4           0               0
```

---

### Timing

Expanding the data:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*(10000//4), ignore_index=True)
# df.shape == (25000, 2)
```

Original Method:

- Gave up at 15 minutes.

New Method:

- 1m 20sec

Throw `pandarallel` at it:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

df[['A']].parallel_apply(get_prev_next_count, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

- 26sec

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is a bug in my code `I won't get the count if there are all true values in the frame, eg np.array( [True, True, True,True, True]).argmin() gives me 0`

Comment: do we have to use a third iterable `all(arr)` to get number of trues is there no way apart from this

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar fixed your logic for finding the first `False`, now it doesn't have to run against the whole frame every time. This speeds things up a ton.

Comment: That's awesome, improves the runtime by a huge margin. Thanks, I ll wait for some more answers, if I don't get more efficient than this, ll accept the same in 2days

Comment: Sounds good, it's still an uncomfortable amount of looping, but 1-2minutes is at least *bearable* compared to what it was before. And, time is a lot closer to linear for larger DataFrames now. I gave it one with 50k rows, and it finished in ~50 seconds (via pandarallel) @HimanshuPoddar